# Next Js dynamically change template layout for page data created in Strapi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi

**The goal:** 
We have a home page called: `https://example.com`
and the homepage has pages called about us, about company, contact us and services respectively which are all stored inside Strapi

```
https://example.com/about-us  
https://example.com/about-company  
https://example.com/contact-us  
https://example.com/services
```

The front-end design is done in nextjs and there are two template layouts created called template1.js and template2.js.

The goal here is that a content manager (CM) working on Strapi should be able to pick any template and render the json data from strapi using the template that was selected by the CM.

Comment: You will likely need to trigger Next build from dashboard, and template name should be passed to Next somehow. I'm unaware of ready solutions for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67229849/dynamically-selecting-nextjs-pages-from-strapi-and-then-rendering-strapi-data-in
I have specified it more accurately in the above question.

Comment: The new question doesn't differ much, the comment above still applies. You need to create Stripe extension that will trigger Next build on UI event. If you run a build with command line then you need to run a build with Node `exec` and pass template name as environment variable like `NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_TEMPLATE=... npm build`.

Comment: Problem is that this will cause problems when there are updates in Strapi.
Is there any other possible way? Maybe creating an API with some other logic.

Comment: You can possibly provide template name as another API and choose between template1 and template2 in Next based on API response.